# camera intent recreates my activity and destroys all my app objects

Tags: java, android

Camera intent kills my activity. I think it is due to an outofmemory error. This happens in s4 alone, but sometimes it works correctly. I'm calling the following intent. When save button is pressed the activity recreated.

Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: can you post full logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Save your objects in the onSavedInstanceState() method. For more information about the Android lifecycle and when you should retrieve/save objects go here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html